# Putting a Grid inside a Canvas

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating an application for Windows Phone 8.1 (non-SilverLight). I want to put a grid class in a canvas class with XAML like below:

[image]

I wish to position the Grid in the middle of the Canvas that means that distance between the top of the grid and the top of the canvas is the same as that between the bottom of the grid and the bottom of the canvas. Similarly, the distance between the left of the grid and the left of the canvas should be the same as that between the right of the grid and the right of the canvas.

How do I do that and ensure that the layout is consistent on all types of screen resolution on different phones?

So far, I have this:

```
<Canvas Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid Width="300" Height="200" Canvas.Left="40" Canvas.Top="40">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>



            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       </Grid>
</Canvas>
```

It is not what I wanted when I deploy to my phone and I know fixing the problem by adjusting the height and width manually is not a good solution.
I am a new in this area and sorry if I used the wrong terminologies.

Please help and guide me >.<

Comment: Why would you like to do that? What are you trying to accomplish using that?

Comment: @CKII wanted to have some spaces between the grid and the canvas so that when I touch on the edges of the grid, I have spaces to display options left, right, top and bottom of the touch point. Is there any better way to do this actually?? Please advise, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two basic options to solve this, you can either use a single grid with a lot of margins, so the grid would not touch the edge of the screen. Or you can use a grid within a gird. A canvas should only be used for graphics work, when you want the controls to have a fixed position no matter the screen size.

For your case, I'd use a grid within a grid. A grid centers everything within it, so that solves your problem. But since you said you wanted to add extra info in the margins, I'd do something like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="Outer>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="Inner" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

That would give you a structure something like this:

```
Outer
-----------
| |     | |
-----------
| |     | |
| |inner| |
| |     | |
-----------
| |     | |
-----------
```

And a place to add more controls in the outer grid.

Note that a grid is a relatively expensive control, so try to avoid placing it when you can you another control, but that shouldn't deter you when it is useful.

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me advice and even teaching me more about grids and canvas. I think I will heed your advice of using a grid within a grid. :D

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are using a `canvas` to position your content grid. You can achieve the layout using the below code if `canvas` is not mandatory.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid Width="300" Height="200" HorizontalAllignment="Center" VerticalAllignment="Center">

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>



            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
       </Grid>
</Grid>
```